# is it possible to truncate my existing crontab file with a bash script?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cron

Part of my application deployment pipeline on AWS includes a bash script that updates the hosts CRON file, in addition to running a ruby install as the user

```sh
sudo -u myuser bash << eof
  echo 'running bundle install'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/wrappers/bundle install
  echo 'install cron tasks'
  (crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo "TZ=America/Los_Angeles")| crontab -
  (crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo "CRON_TZ=America/Los_Angeles")| crontab -
  (crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo "00 13 * * * /bin/bash /var/www/application/bin/daily-notifications.sh")| crontab -
  crontab -l
eof
```

unfortunately In order to update my AMI image I need to first manually go into my crontab file and erase the cron tasks first prior to taking a new image of the OS, because the code above is "appends" each line to the end of the existing file

is it possible in the bash script above to purge the cron tasks programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, per the [crontab manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/crontab):

```
SYNOPSIS
       crontab [ -u user ] file
       crontab [ -u user ] [ -i ] { -e | -l | -r }

DESCRIPTION
[...]
       The -r option causes the current crontab to be removed.
```

So you would use the command `crontab -r`

Comment: success , thanks

Answer (score 1):

Rather than erasing the crontab file and then running a script to append to it (note: the entire `crontab -l 2>/dev/null; ...` bits is there to append instead of replace), why not rewrite the script to just replace it directly?

```
sudo -u myuser bash << OuterEOF
  echo 'running bundle install'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/wrappers/bundle install
  echo 'install cron tasks'
  crontab - << InnerEOF
  TZ=America/Los_Angeles
  CRON_TZ=America/Los_Angeles
  00 13 * * * /bin/bash /var/www/application/bin/daily-notifications.sh
InnerEOF
  crontab -l
OuterEOF
```

Note that this method involves a here-document inside a here-document, so make sure you use different delimiters (and don't indent them, or they won't be recognized). If you don't like that, there are a number of other ways to send multiple lines to the `crontab -` command, like `printf`:

```
...
  printf '%s\n' \
    "TZ=America/Los_Angeles" \
    "CRON_TZ=America/Los_Angeles" \
    "00 13 * * * /bin/bash /var/www/application/bin/daily-notifications.sh" |
    crontab -
...
```